Jamin doesn't launch on Ubuntu Studio 24.04
I installed Jamin using sudo apt install jamin, but Jamin doesn't launch ... (blinking icon and disappears)
My system:
  Système d'exploitation : Ubuntu Studio 24.04
  Version de KDE Plasma : 5.27.11
  Version de KDE Frameworks : 5.115.0
  Version de Qt : 5.15.13
  Version de noyau : 6.8.0-40-lowlatency (64-bit)
  Plate-forme graphique : Wayland
  Processeurs : 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
  Mémoire : 15,5 Gio de mémoire vive
  Processeur graphique : Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 3000
jamin --help show me this :
unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/site”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance jamin: invalid option -- '-' jamin: invalid option -- 'e' Usage: jamin [-dFf:j:n:hprTtvVl:s:c:igD] [inport1 inport2 [outport1 outport2]] – 

$ jamin
jamin 0.98.9
(C) 2003-2013 J. Depner, S. Harris, J. O'Quin, R. Parker and P. Shirkey
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details.
(jamin:20985): dconf-WARNING **: 14:09:29.172: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/site”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
Cannot find plugin 'foo_limiter.so'
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.515: gtk_grid_attach: assertion 'width > 0' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.515: gtk_grid_attach: assertion 'width > 0' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.516: gtk_grid_attach: assertion 'width > 0' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.516: gtk_grid_attach: assertion 'width > 0' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.551: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.551: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.567: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.567: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.572: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.572: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.575: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.576: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.577: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.578: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.578: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.580: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.580: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.581: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.581: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.582: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.582: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.584: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.584: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed
(jamin:20985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.585: invalid cast from 'GtkScale' to 'GtkHScale'
(jamin:20985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.585: invalid cast from 'GtkScale' to 'GtkHScale'
(jamin:20985): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:29.615: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
(jamin:20985): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:29.615: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
(jamin:20985): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:09:29.685: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed

Any idea why Jamin doesn't start?

Needs more details. That is not the full install command for the install. What command or how is it launched after install?

I just looked this software up. It has not been maintained since 2005. It is most likely never going to work on Ubuntu 24.04 https://jamin.sourceforge.net/en/news.html

Ha, sorry about this news, thank you for your answer and link.

Installation done first time with "sudo pat install ardour", no error messages but didn't launch well (bliking Jamin icon and disappear ... Also used the "ubuntu discover" software panel  to remove and reinstall, but same pb, Jamin doesn't launch.

Jamin is version 0.98, so it looks as if the mentioned website is not really up to date. Try to launch jamin via terminal and post error message, probably we can see something more.

"jamin --help" show me this : unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/site”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
jamin: invalid option -- '-'
jamin: invalid option -- 'e'
Usage: jamin [-dFf:j:n:hprTtvVl:s:c:igD] [inport1 inport2 [outport1 outport2]]

Jamin in console gives :  gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed

Please edit the question and add this info, Not as comments. Comments do not stay and many people will not read them. The info for the question all needs to be in one place.

OK David, it's done. Thanks :)

That's likely a bug, I get the same errors, segmentation fault, core dumped. File a bug report here.

Would be nice if somebody can fix or fork Jamin for a suite ...
